# How can I send email with SES using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have an AngularJS website hosted with AWS S3.
I try to send emails with SES using AngularJS (without backend).

Is it possible?
How can I handle the ACCESS/PRIVATE KEY without make it public?

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot think of a way to protect your credentials without some kind of back end script to store the keys in a non-web accessible way.  Anything in AngularJS (or any javascript) is going to be visible to the client.  Wouldn't it be easier to write a tiny script that AngularJS can post to and send the email?

Answer (score 3):

Exposing the credentials needed to send e-mails through SES to you end-users, means they can use those credentials to send any kind of e-mail they want. Thus your SES account will be abused to send SPAM and blocked (and you'll get a large bill).

What you can do is trigger a JavaScript function in the cloud which sends the e-mail. You can deploy JavaScript (node.js) in the cloud with the [AWS lamba service](http://aws.amazon.com/lambda/).

With Lambda you don't need to provision or manage any servers, you just pay for the execution time of your JavaScript function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I knew it was tricky to do this, but I didn't know Lambda.
I'll try this ASAP and keep you in touch.